# Magento 2 and Redis Tokenization

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, redis, aws

I'm looking at implementing ElastiCache Redis (AWS) for a new Magento 2 implementation.  However, I have concerns because ElastiCache isn't covered under the BAA and I could have PII/PHI in my data.  So I'm wondering if Magento 2 and Redis have a tokenization process I could utilize.